# package does not exist - beginnings java

Tags: java, package

I just started to learn Java.
I have a problem I could find already.

I have two classes "Point" and "Rectan" in the same folder "bunio". 
When I create new Point objcet, there is everything OK, but when i try to do something with new Rectan objcet NetBeans tell me "package prostokat does not exist". 
(prostokat = name of Rectan class object)

**My Point class:**

```
    package bunio;
public class Point {
    int x;
    int y;
    int downloadX() {
        return x;
    }
    int downloadY() {
        return y;
    } 
    void showCoordinates(){
        System.out.println("Coordinate x is: "+x);
        System.out.println("Coordinate y is: "+y);   
    }

}
```

**My Rectan Class:**

```
package bunio;

public class Rectan {


    int x1;
    int y1;
    int x2;
    int y2;
    int x3;
    int y3;
    int x4;
    int y4;

void showCoordinates(){
        System.out.println("Point 1 is: "+x1 +", "+y1);    
        System.out.println("Point 1 is: "+x2 +", "+y2); 
        System.out.println("Point 1 is: "+x3 +", "+y3); 
        System.out.println("Point 1 is: "+x4 +", "+y4); 

}
}
```

**And Main**

```
   package bunio;
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Point point1 = new Point();
    point1.x=3;
    point1.y=3;
    point1.showCoordinates();

    Point point2 = new Point();
    point2.x=3;
    point2.y=0;
    point2.showCoordinates();

    Point point3 = new Point();
    point3.x=0;
    point3.y=0;
    point3.showCoordinates();

    Point point4 = new Point();
    point4.x=0;
    point4.y=3;
    point4.showCoordinates();

    }


    Rectan prostokat = new Rectan();
    prostokat.x1=9;
```

And fail appears in the line **"prostokat.x1=9"**.
Message "package prostokat does not exist". I really don't know what to do, the same folder, and code for Point and Rectan classes are analogous.

Comment: statements have to be inside a method block. You have an extra `}` a few lines up which mean this code in not inside `main`  If you use your IDE to format your code for you, these sort of error become more obvious.

Comment: Holy! Peter Lawrey, thanks a lot! 
I was thinking few hours what's wrong. I ended main method to early. Thanks a lot again! :)

Comment: I suggest you use the hotkey for reformatting code regularly. Every time you finish a piece.